Storybook Vite SCSS "does not provide an export named 'default'"
I have a stencil web component library as part of a nx angular monorepo. I tried adding storybook to the stencil library using the nx storybook configuration command using the web-components-vite configuration. When loading storybook I get:
The requested module '/src/components/my-component/my-component.scss?tag=first-component&encapsulation=shadow' does not provide an export named 'default'

.storybook/main.ts
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/web-components-vite';

import { nxViteTsPaths } from '@nx/vite/plugins/nx-tsconfig-paths.plugin';
import { mergeConfig } from 'vite';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../src/components/**/*.@(mdx|stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx))'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-interactions', {
    name: 'storybook-addon-stencil'
  }],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/web-components-vite',
    options: {},
  },

  viteFinal: async (config) =>
    mergeConfig(config, {
      plugins: [nxViteTsPaths()],
    }),
};

export default config;

// To customize your Vite configuration you can use the viteFinal field.
// Check https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/vite#configuration
// and https://nx.dev/recipes/storybook/custom-builder-configs

I have changed the file type to plain css and it builds fine, I believe there is something wrong with it using scss or if you have any clue as to why it fails using scss. I have tried adding the storybook scss addon for webpack but that did nothing
